# Cookie settings on every page

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

As the title says, the cookie settings popup shows up on every page, even after pressing "Accept all cookies".

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

[image: Animated GIF showing the popup re-appear after selecting "Accept all cookies" on reload before and after turning off UBlock Origin. Something for another plugin is shown but it's too small to see. Clicking the "Customize Settings" button does nothing.]

Comment: I've had this a few times throughout the day but it seems to eventually resolve itself...

Comment: First of all, don't press the first button :) SE doesn't need that much info. Check cookies for stackoverflow.com - do they include `OptanonAlertBoxClosed` and `OptanonConsent`?

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks, but pressing `Customize settings` doesn't do anything. Here's a small video to illustrate the problem: https://gofile.io/d/s13Fqf

Comment: @PedroLobito - I was only part-serious (about the first button). A side-note: clicking on "Customize" should open another modal with granulated cookie settings. What is more relevant, though: check the devtools (or whatever you use to check them), are the above 2 cookies present? Are there any console errors as well, btw? Additional info on the browser, version, and mode used, as well as privacy settings would help the discussion a lot. P.s. sorry, don't follow external links - can you reshoot and add to the post as a gif? This way everyone sees this.

Comment: @OlegValter I don't see the modal and there are no console errors. From meta and stackoveflow, I've 4 cookies _ga, acct, prov and sgt. Gif added.

Comment: Clicking the back button and not refreshing will show the dialog as many times as you want. Refresh the page after clicking back to get the latest code & cookies.

Comment: This is weird, but for me I see it pop up for a split second and then it vanishes, I'm guessing either Firefox or UBlock Origin is making it go away

Comment: Also this is a bit off topic, but, I have my browser set to "do not track", why is SE asking me whether I want cookies? Didn't I already indicate very clearly that I don't want tracking?  Also why is SE using the dark pattern of making it easier to opt in than opt out? I know the answer is probably "Advertiser $$$$", but if I go out of my way to say "no" by setting DNT it should be pretty clear I'm not interested.

Comment: @PedroLobito - thanks. Check this request in devtools: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal/consent-popup?bannerVersion=baseline it is fired when you click on the customize settings. Maybe it gets blocked (that should only address the new modal part). As for the cookies - then they are definitely not set correctly for you, the 2 I mentioned must be present.

Comment: @jhr DNT setting and GDPR compliance are not the same. DNT is a preference sites can ignore. GDPR legally requires sites with reach to EU citizens to provide a proper consent UI (and a lot of other stuff as well) but does not get in great detail how it should be implemented. Obviously, no profit-driven company is interested in being the "ethical one" unless strictly necessary (read: huge fines for non-compliance). To approve of SE for once, their consent modal is one of the more modest ones in attempts to goat users to accept tracking cookies.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MEG8Qs6.jpg

Comment: @OlegValter personally I am fine with having Stack read all my cookies. I care about privacy but I trust them, so it's _slightly_ misleading to say you should never click that button :). Note: I find legal stuff a pain, and only read through the first paragraph of the Cookie Policy.

Comment: Also, the cookie settings is completely busted with high contrast black on.

Comment: It's hard to see all the extensions you have installed, but is it possible you're blocking something from `cookielaw.org`? They're relying on that site for some part of the cookie-check process -- I found I couldn't get the box to go away until I configured NoScript to allow `cookielaw.org`.

Comment: @OlegValter Yep, I know the difference between "legal" and "optional" in this case. This whole "cookie" exchange is pretty much just this: (My Browser): I do not want to be tracked, SE: Do you want cookies? Please uncheck every single tracking option. *It should be obvious that I'm going to uncheck those*, I shouldn't have to say it again. They can legally ignore DNT of course, but it's a bad faith move to join the herd of websites that ask me to confirm on each and every single one that I don't want tracking. SE is part of the problem here.

Comment: @jrh - not sure I understand what your point above was then. SE is a profit-driven company, no more, no less. I wish we stopped reasoning about this type of company in terms of ethics: as I am sure you know, there are 2 things that could cause a profit-driven company to comply (both boiling down to a single reason: being unable to make money): 1. Public image damage. 2. Huge fine or operation ban. Expecting good faith here is, in my opinion, a bit naive: "explicit consent" policy at least ensures the practices become visible (btw, tracking options are disabled by default in SE's version).

Comment: @OlegValter I don't really expect good faith here. It'd be nice but I don't expect it these days. I've seen other sites do it better, I've seen some sites that did it worse too. Tom Scott has a [pretty good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFRjZtYs3wY) about this. If SE put the effort in to design this dialog, they could have made better choices, it's not a matter of compelling them to do something, it's more asking why they chose this option to spend dev time on. IMO this was unambiguously designed to encourage users to opt in to tracking to make the popup go away.

Comment: Also, I know I'm making a rather opinionated point here but if nobody says "these things are annoying" nothing will change. It doesn't affect me much because I adblock heavily, but for a while SE wasn't as bad as other sites, now it's getting worse. [There's better ways to meet GDPR requirements](https://youtu.be/v_W0wR4AClk?t=422), they could've done better. I wouldn't be as bothered about this if SE didn't practically sell itself on having well behaved ads and distraction free content at one point; I know things change after the startup dream dries up but I don't have to like it.

Comment: @jrh I had lots of problems with SO moderators in the past regarding privacy, namely using google CDN for jquery, and tend not to engage on such debates anymore because they temporary suspended my account for doing so, but for the record, I fully support your pov.

Comment: Yeah, that's about as far as I'm planning on taking this. IMO it's not a great design and they could have done better. I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @jhr, I meant as a whole, not SE specifically - what I mean is they are doing it only because they are forced to, and each try to circumvent what's being imposed on them as hard as they can (reminds me of what tobacco companies try get away with on a technicality). Thankfully, SE has a very vocal community to try out some of the most shady practices, but I agree they are not among the best examples (making "accept all" a primary button is a very disappointing decision from my POV). P.s. dev time - it seems like not too much of it was spent: the `cookielaw.org` (or, frankly, the company [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] behind it, Cookiepro), sells services for ensuring compliance. Anyways, to avoid distracting the main conversation further - don't get me wrong, I don't disagree with your point of view that things could and should be handled better, just feel that respecting user privacy preferences will never be a willful priority for profit-driven companies. P.s. Signing off on the comment you made above as well.

Comment: When I click "Customize settings", the box doesn't even go away.

Comment: Why in the first place is SE pushing me to accept ***all cookies*** instead of the strict necessary?

Comment: @OlegValter Also for me the tracking option was *not* disabled by default, I had to manually uncheck it just now when I visited a new site.

Comment: @jrh - either you imply the devs are [explicitly lying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent/359701#comment1199642_359396) or there is a bug - please, do report it on the announcement page. Works just fine for me with only the first option selected (that's what is expected from the GDPR-compliant consent): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ikuy.gif

Comment: @MrUpsidown - is this a rhetorical question? :)

Comment: @OlegValter I definitely do not see what you're seeing in the gif, when I click Customize Settings everything is enabled. Maybe it's because my IP address isn't one from a EU country? Though from your profile it looks like you're from Russia, I can't really explain why the options are unchecked for you but checked for me. It might be a bug, or it might be region-specific. In any case, legal or not, my "default options" are not very nice at all. Luckily my adblockers/firefox would eat these cookies anyway.

Comment: @jrh - yup, GDPR should not apply to my account (and I make it pretty trivial to determine), but the options are unchecked. Your case is strange - given that you say *all* options are checked for you, could it be you accidentally clicked on "accept all" before (that's more of a rhetorical question, not sure that's traceable)? Certainly would be a good idea to report if you think you did not give prior consent. Because if you didn't that is a major concern.

Comment: @OlegValter  [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q7Oy.png) what I see on Chrome (I almost never use Chrome for anything), in incognito mode with Adblock disabled, I'm not sure how to get a more "vanilla" setup than that. I guess I could spin up a virtual PC. I wonder if there's special behavior for US users.

Comment: @jrh - there is an interesting thing to check. There should be a request to the CDN that serves the consent config: https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/{{id here}}/en.json. If you check for the `Status` field of items under the `Groups` field - which value are they set to?

Comment: @OlegValter the status seems to be "inactive" for all of them, but they are [clearly enabled in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WTMJ.png)

Comment: @OlegValter `cdn.cookielaw.org` is blocked by my network and this should be the root of the problem.

Comment: @PedroLobito - pretty sure it is the root issue for you. From what I've learnt, the initial popup is served by SO, so it loads regardless of whether or not `cdn.cookielaw.org` is blocked. Then, upon clicking the button, several requests are issued, returning JSON config and scripts to control the consent UX from the CDN. If those are blocked, then it perfectly explains the issue you have with not being able to proceed to config. jrh's is what bothers me, seems like everything is loaded they are still shown as "on" by default.

Comment: @OlegValter I don't get it either.  We're getting into "silly" territory at this point, but I am not using a VPN, Chromium is not old `Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)`, I don't have a pi-hole or any other "man in the middle" blocker device, I'm running Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 x86_64 but I remember seeing it on Windows 10 20H2 as well, and the Chromium I ran this test on had zero extensions enabled. Other than ripping apart their frontend JS for clues (I can try, but it's not my specialty) I can't think of anything else to check.

Comment: I've started a bounty on the bug report over on MSE: [The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091/158100)

Comment: @jrh - although you probably don't care since you are not from EU, but apart from being a concerning issue, it is also a direct violation of GDPR Recital 32: "Silence, pre-ticked boxes or inactivity should not therefore constitute consent." if that is intentional, so I hope this is a bug. Given your setup I also ran out of ideas unless some sort of geolocation is involved. The Javascript SDK provided for the modal reveals there is a global object `OneTrust` exposed with some methods of interest. In particular, `getGeolocationData` (empty props for me due to high privacy settings), [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] and `GetDomainData` which returns the parsed config. Can you check what the latter returns? For example, of particular interest are: `ConsentModel` should be `{ Name: "opt-in" }` and `Groups` which should mirror the raw JSON where each group except `C0001` has `Status: "inactive"`.

Comment: This is still happening for me, on a PC that doesn't have adblock I saw this thing probably 10 times in one day.

Comment: It's happening to everyone, but mods simply don't care or say the problem is solved. Don't expect any changes soon.

Comment: I installed the Chrome extension called "I Dont Care About Cookies" and it got rid of the cookie banners on all of the stackexchange sites.

Comment: This is happening again on the latest Firefox on Windows 10. Malice or stupidity?

Comment: I use stackoverflow less because this cookie window makes me crazy. Can't remove it whatever I do.

Comment: This makes me crazy. I don't almost use stockoverflow, stackexchange, superuser anymore because of this cookie window. There's no way I get rid of them no matter what I click.

Comment: I am having the same problem in May 2023. I'm on windows 11, and firefox / chrome browsers show the same problem. I have to accept something on every page I visit on stackOverflow.com, to remove the cookie popup that hides page contents. I am really surprised that it is not being taken care of.

Answer (score 89):

I think they are using third-party cookies to do this (don't do that).

I reported this [months ago](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358#359663), and they didn't change anything and didn't even
respond.

I have set my browser (Firefox) to block these types of cookies, as it is a
privacy violation. I am not going to allow these Stack Exchange cookies, despite
any warm fuzzy feelings I may have toward Stack Exchange. So to deal with it, I have added these filters to uBlock Origin:

```
stackexchange.com##.js-consent-banner
stackoverflow.com##.js-consent-banner
superuser.com##.js-consent-banner
```

Some people have mentioned Stack Exchange is trying to call JavaScript from
`cookielaw.org`. I do currently allow JavaScript from `cookielaw.org`, but only
when visiting `cbsnews.com`, as I think it breaks otherwise. I am not going to
extend that to Stack Exchange, until we get some kind of response from employees,
and maybe not even then. That JavaScript shouldn’t be required to make Stack
Exchange usable.

Comment: They seem to be first-party: issued by the same domain that's (in the case of SO, `.stackoverflow.com`). Also, I have 3P cookies blocked by default for all sites. Besides, afaik it would be a huge problem for Apple devices due to ITP.

Comment: They're certainly using third-party javascript (from `cookielaw.org`) to set the cookies -- I found I couldn't get the box to go away until I configured noscript to allow `cookielaw.org`.

Comment: After accepting to dismiss can I revoke these as I don't want them? Probably a meta question in itself.

Comment: @QHarr - you can go to devtools and delete both cookies [or do it via other means] :) Or [join tripleee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362727/786798) in their quest on Uber Meta for brining these settings to the profile

Comment: @QHarr - NP. Do keep it around, the more fuss around privacy concerns, the better for all of us, I think.

Comment: It's very strange, I've set my browser to block all third party cookies and I also didn't allow cookielaw.org in NoScript. When I click on the "Customize settings" button and disable everything, it stops appearing ever again (it's community specific though).

Comment: @Clockwork I, too, have my browser set to block third party cookies and don't allow cookielaw.org. When I click the button, nothing happens (except that a loading icon temporarily blinks into view, sometimes), so I can't disable stuff.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Which is what I find strange. I should have the same trouble since I have the same settings. I can't help but wonder why it's working for me.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this is part of a current series of bugs that the team is looking into.

Comment: I use a VPN. Turning it off briefly, reloading the page, and then turning the VPN back on seemed to work.

Comment: Same here. It makes me crazy.

Comment: why don't they try to resolve it?

Comment: Customize settings doesn't work in my browser. Nothing happens

Answer (score 13):

In my case, despite having `uBlock Origin` disabled and allowing scripts from `cookielaw.org`, I could only solve this problem by opening Stack Overflow in a new browser (Brave), accept the `Strictly Necessary` cookies and check which cookies had been created after this:

```
OptanonAlertBoxClosed: 2021-03-31T15:41:36.781Z
OptanonConsent: isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Wed+Mar+31+2021+16%3A41%3A36+GMT%2B0100+(British+Summer+Time)&version=6.10.0&hosts=&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0003%3A0%2CC0004%3A0%2CC0002%3A0%2CC0001%3A1
```

I then recreated these cookies on Firefox and the popup was gone.
While this is far from an optimal solution, it allows me to use Stack Overflow without having to close the cookie popup on every page load.

Comment: How bizarre...  Are you sure nothing gets blocked? From the looks of it, the conditions for the modal to work properly seem to be ideal.

Comment: I'm on a strict network environment regarding privacy, but that doesn't seem to affect the way Brave handles  SO cookie agreement, so It must be FF related.

Comment: Firefox doesn't like it at all. On my phone (running FF with uBlock Origin), the popup shows up on every single page, and the "customize settings" button does nothing. On my computer, it tends to pop up and disappear right after (potentially because of a plugin; debugging that takes aaaaaages). Fortunately doesn't appear when I'm on my own network with pi-hole. Extremely broken though - would've been a lot better if they just stayed away from a third party service on this one. It overall seems like a privacy hell based on how my various blockers treat the site as well.

Comment: How do I manually create these cookies in FF?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Please see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/k2kEr3s.png)

Comment: This is what happens when web sites bog down in third party scripts and cookies. I just use uBlock Origin to hide the popup and I’ll probably let Cookie Auto Delete clean up afterwards.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue where the popup would come back after each page refresh on `www.stackoverflow.com`, regardless of which button I press or what cookies I chose to enable.
But once I visited `meta.stackoverflow.com` and accepted only `Functional cookies`, the popup was no longer shown anywhere.

So the culprit was that `www.stackoverflow.com` only sets one cookie: `OptanonConsent` which stores your preferences of allowed cookies in the following format:

```
groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A0%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&datestamp=Wed+Mar+31+2021+19%3A09%3A03+GMT-0400+(Eastern+Standard+Time)&version=6.10.0&hosts=&isIABGlobal=false&AwaitingReconsent=false&geolocation=%3B
```

Where

- `C0001` = `Strictly Necessary`
- `C0002` = `Performance Cookies`
- `C0003` = `Functional Cookies`
- `C0004` = `Targeting Cookies`

Each setting followed by `%3A` (which is URL encoded column `:` sign) and a number `0` or `1`, where `1` means enabled. So in the example above, only `Strictly Necessary` and `Functional Cookies` are enabled.

**To prevent the popup from showing again, another cookie must be set: `OptanonAlertBoxClosed`** with any value (even empty), by default it sets with the date cookie preferences were changed, i.e `2021-03-31T23:09:03.572Z`

For whatever reason `www.stackoverflow.com` does not set this cookie.

Comment: Any way to set the cookie manually?

Comment: Sure, via developer tools (F12)

Answer (score 10):

This happens when you use a blocker to block scripts or XHR from cookielaw.org.

I ran into it, when I had set a default policy of block all third party (except images and css).

Answer (score 4):

This was something we had to track down and reproduce. We found that the issue was happening to less than 1% of users who have configured browser settings or ad blocking installed. We’ve since updated the user experience to display an error message with more information when this occurs.

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate in your post on the underlying problem (or link to a relevant MSE post if all the info is there)? I think providing details on the matter will benefit everyone.

Comment: @OlegValter probably third party cookies related. BTW Des, I found this issue on any browser I used.

Comment: @Des Hi, you've tagged this question as "status-completed" but nothing changed, meaning the popup is recurring and there's no way dismiss it permanently..

Comment: This is definitely still an issue, it never stopped happening for me. (I don't get it *every* time I visit a Stack Exchange, but maybe about once a week they all start giving me the popup again.) It seems that more recent questions are being closed as a duplicate of this one, so it seems like it would be a good idea to remove the [tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: I seriously doubt it is 1% of users, I am using Safari with no adblocker and it comes up every time. It is immensely annoying.

Comment: It is still happening to me. I have adblock enabled and I don't see any information or error message on clicking "Accept all Cookies"

Comment: I'm using stackoverflow since 12 years. The last 2 years I almost didn't use it anymore because of those awful cookies. The cookie window is still there on every page. I have FF Browser and Ublock turned off. With or without ad blocker nothing works. Terrible!!!

Comment: Added Hush extension to my Safari browser. No more annoying cookie pop-ups. 

Answer (score 2):

This can be related to Ghostery. Pause Ghostery and answer the popup. When Ghostery is resumed, the problem does not recur.

This is still a SO issue. No other website I've encountered requires this workaround.

Comment: Ghostery blocks cookies. If you can't store the user's choice, then the popup is going to re-appear. This is not a SO issue, it's a plugin issue. Ghostery needs to whitelist that choice.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is a deliberate design choice given the omnipresence of adblockers, privacy plugins and browsers rejecting third-party cookies. I have to dismiss the cookie popup every couple of weeks on Brave, and get an error when doing so.

Comment: @Cerbrus Again, only SO requires this.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, It's not a deliberate design choice to _not_ implement workarounds for browser extensions like this. It's working exactly as intended: No cookies are stored, 'cause you've blocked them.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is a choice to want to store that cookie as third-party cookie (I suppose, I haven't looked into the details). It's not a "workaround", it's a fact of life in 2023. Just like those site that store the "I don't want any non-necessary cookies" cookie for like three days and then ask again. That's a choice.

Comment: You're nitpicking an implementation that's probably as old as the site itself... If you're gonna use a addon like this, there's gonna be side-effects. Deal with them...

Comment: @Cerbrus I am not nitpicking nor using addons. The site has been showing the cookie popup every couple of weeks for a couple of months now while showing a generic error it can't save cookies. Rejecting third-party cookies is and has been native browser functionality that site builders have to accommodate for, and if not, that's just plain ignorance or incompetence or annoying users into accepting cookies.

Comment: Thanks @KevinKrumwiede it worked.