# The copy-paste budget can be easily bypassed without The Key™

Tags: bug, code-vulnerabilities, april-fools

[The new copy-paste budget](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406398/8384089) can be easily be bypassed using a simple JavaScript hack:

```javascript
localStorage["copyBudget"] = "Infinity";
```

Now people can copy-paste all they want without The Key™!  It should be patched.

Comment: This is very concerning.

Comment: Also pretty cool...

Comment: This is just the first release of our enhanced copying experience. For now, we're just on the honor system - we didn't get _quite_ enough time to implement copy blocking _(yet)_

Comment: Shhh! You're [not supposed to post](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) security vulnerabilities to Meta!

Comment: @zcoop98 Even if it's a site of developers?

Comment: @KylePollard To do that, you'd probably have to hack every computer that accesses Stack Overflow.  A code golf challenge!

Comment: @Anonymous - given how readily folks [click on things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406344/11407695) around here, this should not be a problem too hard to solve :)

Comment: @OlegValter How would you get people to click "run"?

Comment: @Anonymous - "we now have a desktop app - be the first to try out the new cool features" :) Anyways, just joking. P.s. I like how the budget counter gets into negative values the more you copy. Also - doesn't budget get reset to 2 if it is more than that value upon next copy?

Comment: @OlegValter It seems to, but if you put 500, it would show 2 even though it takes 500 copies.

Comment: @Anonymous - yup, just mentioned that `Infinity` gets reset to 2. Also major props for being line aware as it seems: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR1OB.gif :) P.s. An even more robust version: `document.addEventListener("keyup", ({ ctrlKey, key }) => {
    if(ctrlKey && key.toLowerCase() === "c") {
        localStorage.copyBudget = "Infinity";
    }
});`

Comment: @OlegValter `addEventListener("copy", e=>e.stopImmediatePropagation(), true);` would be both more straightforward and more robust, e.g your code wouldn't work on macOs devices where we copy using the `metaKey`, nor for users copying through other means than a keyboard.

Comment: @Kaiido - yeah, I agree, the `copy` event is even better, didn't think too much about the upgrade :)

Comment: Wow, nine upvotes!  I thought this would get closed as off-topic.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402944/3730834), it is called "vulnerability" rather than bug.

Comment: @Thor-x86_128 - let's go further and specify that this is an "exploit" :)

Comment: I've heard rumours that user don't vote nor review enough on Stack. Perhaps we should get an option to "buy" copy-rights. One vote gets one copy and one review gives two. Then there's be no need to steal copy-rights by hacking ;)

Comment: @Scratte Even if hacking's far, far easier?