# Cookie Pop-up Un-dismissable in Safari

Tags: bug, user-experience, popup, safari

Related to: [Cookie settings on every page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406344/cookie-settings-on-every-page)

Please note that I say it's related; I'm not posting a link to the question and then proceeding to repeat it. It is related, though.

I have been getting this prompt a **lot** lately, but it's been on mobile (Android) and Windows (Firefox) for the most part until today. I can always customize settings and verify that they haven't turned on non-critical cookies, save, and get the prompt to disappear.

The issue is that today I got out my MacBook, and hitting the "Customize settings" button does nothing, and the prompt doesn't go away. I'm on the latest point release of Catalina, 11.2.3 and using Safari 14.0.3.

I'm not going to see what happens when I "Accept all cookies" because I refuse to share that information. I am using the AdGuard extension, but the issue persists if disabled. I also use 1Password and Pocket extensions, just for completeness in reporting.

For now, I have added a custom rule to block the box, but it's still an issue that needs fixing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookie settings on every page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406344/cookie-settings-on-every-page). Note that this has been reported already, and that it happens on all browsers, so this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It's related, I state as much, but it's not a duplicate. It's not that it's appearing. It's that **I can't dismiss it or customize settings** on Safari. That's not the point of the proposed dupe.

Comment: If you want to use that question as a catch-all, change its title, and edit the question to include all the issues surrounding the pop-up.

Comment: If this is a SE wide issue it should be migrated to https://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @sweenish I don't like using questions in that way. However, the question I linked does adress the fact that the popup is _not dismissable_, and that the customize settings button doesn't work. It doesn't have to be closed IMO.

Comment: on my mobile i get all the time set the cooies please again and again

Comment: I will edit this in, but Customize settings has worked for me everywhere *except* Safari. I get to make my choices and save and get the prompt to go away. It still shows up too much, but my problem has been specific to Safari.

Comment: @bad_coder don't suggest stuff get migrated because it is a "system wide issue".  Meta.SO works just as well as Meta.SE.  It doesn't get any more attention if asked on either site.  IT is actually best here so people can see the issue and we can close dups against it

Comment: @psubsee2003 that would be a meta thread by itself, I still think network wide issues belong on meta.SE. There are over 170 sites on the network and a lot of users aren't on SO.

Comment: that why network wide issues belong on the per-site meta.  No one except SE diehards even know MSE exists, so they won't look at stuff there

Comment: Besides that it doesn't need migrating, it would be a dupe there (as much as it is here): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091/158100

Comment: @bad_coder that meta thread already exist and has an answer [*Put simply, MSE isn't something you even need to know about or think about, unless you want to.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250073/578411). Don't think for the OP.

Comment: See also [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250152/11682469)

Comment: @sweenish like you I don't think this is a duplicate, because I see a ton of browser specific issues being raised. In any case the linked meta posts don't say the question should not be migrated (contrary to what some of the posters were claiming) or that it wouldn't be in your best interest sir - after all having 1k on meta is fun because you get to see vote counts there.

Comment: Similar here. I see that cookie popup ever 2 days or so and think: when I allowed basic cookies, then why in hell didn't you remember that and ask me over and over? Annoying isn't the right word for that.

Comment: Added Hush extension to my Safari browser! No more annoying cookie pop-ups. 