# Unable to "Customize settings" in cookie popup, it never goes away, always covers content

Tags: bug, privacy, popup, cookies

In Safari with AdBlock + Safari's Content Blockers + Safari's Tracking protection.

This happens on every page; the logs below contain the page I captured them on.

These are the logs from the developer console:

```
Content blocker prevented frame displaying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash from loading a resource from https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js
https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
WebSocket connection to 'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 500
https://clc.stackoverflow.com/timeout.gif?ab=0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The last one occurs when I click "Customize settings". I see a little spinning gif (probably the https://clc.stackoverflow.com/timeout.gif image?) for half a second, then it disappears, and subsequent clicks on "Customize settings" are unresponsive, no change.

"Accept all cookies" doesn't work either.

I think I remember accepting the minimum required cookies from this popup a while ago, so I was surprised to see it reappear.

[image: The "Your privacy" popup with options to "Accept all cookies" or "Customize settings", both of which are unresponsive.]

Edit: Unfortunately, [Cookie Pop-up Un-dismissable in Safari](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406530/cookie-pop-up-un-dismissable-in-safari) does not answer my question because I cannot "add a custom rule to block the box", neither in Safari's Content Blockers nor AdBlock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cookie Pop-up Un-dismissable in Safari](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406530/cookie-pop-up-un-dismissable-in-safari)

Comment: Just commenting to say that posting this issue was made much more difficult by the popup, because it was covering the "Review your question" and "Answer your question" buttons. That was an extremely frustrating 5 minutes trying to get enough display height on my laptop to see them.

Comment: @JeanneDark Unfortunately not – I'm not able to "add a custom rule to block the box"

Comment: so... just add a temporary exception for `cdn.cookielaw.org`? SE chose a third-party solution that loads an SDK when you click "customize settings" (the popup is shown at all because it is SE's markup), so if you are not able to block the popup or allow the CDN, you will have to live with it.

Comment: Also, Apple's ITP does wonders for annoying iOS users in that regards, because there is a high chance that the 2 cookies set upon accepting or customizing consent are likely to get expired in a week (first-party cookies set via `document.cookie`), and the popup will show up again.

Comment: Hi @OlegValter, what do you mean by "Apple's ITP"? What does ITP stand for? I'm on macOS, not iOS. Also "the popup will show up again" isn't the problem here; the problem is that I cannot dismiss it at all.

Comment: I'm able to use many, many other websites that also have "Customize settings" that open a second popup, without having to add to my AdBlock whitelist. Those websites do not frustrate me as much as this one. Only here am I forced to whitelist a url. If StackOverflow isn't usable without turning off ad blockers, then that should be explained by StackOverflow somewhere in its Privacy Policy or the popup itself, not in an assortment of Meta questions and answers.

Comment: @HenryBlyth - ITP stands for "Intelligent Tracking Prevention". Since you did not specify which Safari it is, the assumption was that you are on mobile (but that does not matter much - ITP is active either way). Re: showing up - I was responding to the "I was surprised to see it reappear" part. Re: whitelist - well, thank the decision to use a third-party provider for the "meat" of the popup. Unfortunately, I don't know of anything short of temporarily adding the domain to the whitelist or setting the 2 cookies (see the other Q&As for that).