# Stack Overflow has eaten too many cookies and developed amnesia

Tags: bug, user-experience, cookies

Every few days, when I first visit Stack Overflow, I am greeted again by the "Your Privacy" cookie settings popup:

[image: "Your Privacy" pop-up dialog]

I click "Accept all cookies" and don't get the same prompt again for a day or two (which, I believe, makes this different from a previously reported issue: [Cookie settings on every page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406344/cookie-settings-on-every-page)). But in about two days I get the same again. I do not clear cache, I do not clear cookies, I do not logout/login (I'm always logged in), I do not use any browser extension/plugin/ad blocker, I don't do anything that might cause these settings to be reset. I'm also talking about just Stack Overflow, *not* browsing another SE site which is a different domain hence might need another consent explicitly. I just browse Stack Overflow "clean" (without anything I think of that might cause cookies to stop working) on macOS Big Sur + Safari 14.1.

Since I don't think SE cookie policy changes literally every two days, why am I getting this consent every few days or so?

Comment: Pretty sure this is Safari related thing. Can’t find the reference atm, but I remember something about Safari’s  privacy mode causing this kind of thing. (Also, I experience this on iOS, but not on desktop Firefox)

Comment: It should still be considered a bug.  This behavior also happens with Chromium browsers.

Comment: I feed SO a cookie everyday. It's annoying, but SO always asks so politely...

Comment: I had that at least once at chrome today. I am afraid there were some space cookies strayed in :-P

Comment: It could be that the browser is having problems. Have you tried using a different browser, e.g. Firefox?

Comment: @AndrewMorton no I didn't, but considering the comments above it also happens on Chromium browsers too.

Comment: So besides giving you insuline resistance with the inevitable results that follow from that (diabetes and making you fat), eating too many cookies also gives you amnesia? Why are tasty things always so bad for you.

Comment: @Gimby the problem is that they are eating too much, not that they are eating at all.

Comment: Wish I could vote this up more. Could anything be more embarrassing than the purveyors of technical knowledge being unable to get cookies working properly?

Comment: FWIW, I don’t have this problem in Chrome on either Windows or macOS but I do still occasionally get the cookie pop up using Chrome on iOS. I suspect that there’s some setting I can adjust in the regular browser that doesn’t exist in the mobile version.

Comment: I use Safari. I don't seem to have a similar problem on other websites.

Comment: Why not store the choice in user preferences rather than another cookie?

Comment: @DaveL17 it could only be set if your user preferences if you are actually logged in. That privacy nonsense must work regardless of your login status.

Comment: @Gimby - good point; didn't consider that it needs to work for *everyone*. It's just so meta (storing cookie preferences in a cookie). I routinely wipe my cookie folders--sometimes multiple times per day--so I'm having to set this choice ***a lot***.

Comment: From SuperUser, [Delete all cookies except those from certain sites](https://superuser.com/questions/1572039/delete-all-cookies-except-those-from-certain-sites)

Comment: Any idea how to solve this? This is really annoying and forces me to accept all cookies while I don't want to, just because it is a one click.

Comment: @Artium I don't know. I think I've learned to live with it, and accepted that StackOverflow is just... cookie-hungry, just like me.

Comment: Old thread, but I'm plagued by this at EVERY visit to SO now. It started a few weeks ago. I use Chrome, but I didn't change any cookie settings in ages.

Comment: I have the same problem as @LucMorin: I have to accept cookies EVERY time I click on a link on stackoverflow. I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu and this also started suddenly. It is possible that it started after an update but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I use FireFox on Windows 10.   I see the "ask about cookies" behavior once or twice a day.   SO hasn't got a fix for this?

Comment: "My browser made the site stop working, site, please fix!"

Comment: try the uBlock Origin element picker function.  open the uBlock extension, click the dropper icon (second from the left), select the annoying cookie window, then click create.  going forward, you won't see it.   if this doesn't work or you don't know how to use the feature, google: ublock origin element picker

Comment: @KevinB it would seem that many different browsers and OSes are exhibiting the same behavior when visiting Stack Overflow, so I don't quite get your attempt at derision. Are you suggesting that all browsers, on all OSes, suddenly decided to gang up on SO?

Comment: I have this issue using Firefox on MacOS for every page and every page refresh. I use uBlock Origin and tried disabling filters there to no avail. I finally added a cosmetic filter for the element containing the cookies prompt (see comment from @Taco_Buffet).